# In AWS how do I add an API key to my API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway, api-key

Hello:  I've been following two tutorials in the AWS documentation:

creating the sample pet store API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-from-example.html)

...and creating an API key (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html#api-gateway-usage-plan-create-apikey).

When I test the pet store get method with the provided URL, it returns:

> Welcome to your Pet Store API You have successfully deployed your
> first API. You are seeing this HTML page because the GET method to the
> root resource of your API returns this content as a Mock integration.
>
> The Pet Store API contains the /pets and /pets/{petId} resources. By
> making a GET request to /pets you can retrieve a list of Pets in your
> API. If you are looking for a specific pet, for example the pet with
> ID 1, you can make a GET request to /pets/1.
>
> You can use a REST client such as Postman to test the POST methods in
> your API to create a new pet. Use the sample body below to send the
> POST request:
>
> {
> "type" : "cat",
> "price" : 123.11 }

Now I go to the API Gateway -> API -> Resources ->  -> Method Request -> API Key Required and change it to "True" and redeploy.

When I go to the provided URL to test, now the page returns:

> {"message":"Forbidden"}

Which makes sense... I told it API required = true, right?

So my question is, how do I pass the API key?  So that I don't get the "forbidden" result?  I didn't see that in the tutorial links I pasted above and haven't been able to find elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain if neither of the above scenarios are working for you? Would be good to get this resolved for you, it might be possible more details are required to resolve this :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams.  I responded to Oxi's comment and have follow up questions.  I did not respond to yours because it didn't address my question and I had already red the link your provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You Create a `Usage Plans`
2. Attach this usage plan to your API and Stage
3. Create an `API Key`
4. Now invoke your API with header named `x-api-key` and value of it is the `API Key` created in step-3

Sample:
`curl -i -H "x-api-key: Cd2YiWs8Fv8Lg6njI0wXf1iiNOE94XjM3EQe8567" -X GET https://7r9cvghbf4.execute-api.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/dd/pets`

Comment: I have a usage plan per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-usage-plans.html.  I have an API key in that usage plan.  It still throws the {"message":"Forbidden"} result when clicking on the link (your curl example works for me though).  I have two questions:  1. is it not possible to use an API key with the URL AWS provides?  2.  is passing the key in your curl example secure?

Comment: And This Usage plan attached to API stage ?  1. You send this API key with the url aws gives you for the API stage "AS HEADER x-api-key"  2. sending it as header is as safe as sending uname/password as request body. curl is easy to show that's why i used curl. you can use any other way of consuming http url. to use it from browser, your app javascript should set the header.

Comment: Understand and thanks for the reply... but if I curl -i -H "x-api-key: Cd2YiWs8Fv8Lg6njI0wXf1iiNOE94XjM3EQe8567", isn't that exposing the key?  I thought that's what secrets manager was for... store the API key there and access the secret(s) that way?!

Comment: 1) The API is a HTTPS, So its Secure. 2) The Header is Always send with the request, its just that with CURL, you will see it right away. with the browser you have to open developer console to see it. So The header is safe with the person firing the API 3) An outsider with an out side tool using your API, you have to give him the KEY

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've followed all steps for creating the API key you can use this API key by specifying it in the `x-api-key` header within your request.

> You distribute API keys to your customers and require them to pass the API key as the X-API-Key header of each incoming request.

More information for using API keys in API Gateway is available on: [Choose an API key source - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-key-source.html)